# Flutter doctor network resources error about cocoapods

Tags: flutter, dart, cocoapods

[cmd error image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTlwW.png)

```
 Network resources
    X A cryptographic error occurred while checking "https://cocoapods.org/": Handshake error in client
      You may be experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, your network may be compromised, or you may have malware
      installed on your computer.
```

Flutter install, env have set
PUB_HOSTED_URL https://pub.flutter-io.cn
FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL https://storage.flutter-io.cn

My Operate System is Windows 11

I've try 'flutter channel master' not working at all..
How could i fix that? But cocoapods goes error...

Comment: Please don't post image of the error. Edit your question and add error logs in the question